# How to parse multipart correctly in java 8?

Tags: java, parsing, web

I have a question, what is better in java 8 to parse the information coming in this way from the request:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"
```

I think there is some library for multipart parsing, but I can't find one for parsing not from a file

Comment: Depending on what frameowrk/library you use to implement the web part there are various options for this

Comment: @rascio, I use ejb

Comment: What exactly do you want to parse out of that string? `String[] parts = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"id\"".split("\\s*[:;]\\s*");`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd, after this line is the value, for example: 6110f91770726062870a4316
and I want to get these values by key

Comment: Then I would use regex, but to show you the expression, the line with the key is required